# Check null or empty string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, string

I would like to display 'reason not explicited' if the user doesn't fill this field or the user input if he fills it.
With this code, I don't understand why but even if I fill the field, it is going to display 'reason not explicited'.

```
    private string reason;
    public string Reason
    {
        get
        {
            return this.reason;
        }
        set
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Reason))
                this.reason = "reason not explicited";
            else this.reason = value;
        }
    }

    [Pure]
    public static bool IsNullOrEmpty(String value) {
        return (value == null || value.Length == 0);
    }
```

Comment: `if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) this.reason = "reason not explicited" ...;`

Comment: Use some basic client side validation instead to display the appropriate validation message. You can also use property attributes if you are using mvc validation. Do not hard code this into your model logic.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

just use `value` in your setter to handle the correct behavior

```
set
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        this.reason = "reason not explicited";
    else 
        this.reason = value;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Because you are checking the property instead of the value.
Your current code sets the value of the property only if it's null or empty.
It should be

```
    set
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            this.reason = "reason not explicited";
        else this.reason = value;
    }
```

Or even better:

```
    set
    {
        this.reason = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) ? "reason not explicited": value;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to check `value`, not `this.Reason`:

```
public string Reason
    {
        get
        {
            return this.reason;
        }
        set
        {
            this.reason = string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)
              ? "reason not explicited"
              : value; 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this line of code

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Reason))
```

When you are trying to get the value of this property, calls it's getter, which returns value of `reason` field. And this field is not filled with correct value at the moment you are trying to get value of it.

So you should modify your code to check if null or empty string of concrete input value:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass **value** to the function IsNullOrEmpty function

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                this.reason = "reason not explicited";
            else this.reason = value;
```

Answer (score 0):

The setter will trigger when you change(assign) the value, so if the user skip that field means the setter will not trigger. But the getter will trigger when you access the value of the property. So in your case if you apply the logic inside the get means it will display the `"reason not explicited"` if the reason is null or empty. So the new logic would be like the following:

```
 get
 {
     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.reason))
         return "reason not explicited";
     else this.reason = value;
         return this.reason;
 }
 set
 {
     this.reason = value;  
 }
```

Another solution will be like this:

Initialize the backup property with the `"reason not explicited"` so even if the user skip the field(setter will not trigger) you will get the default value to be printed. And you have to update the backup property based on the `value`

```
private string reason = "reason not explicited";

public string Reason
{
    get { return this.reason; }
    set
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            this.reason = "reason not explicited";
        else
            this.reason = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Getter should not change values.

Comment: Wrong solution.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it. Getter should return actual value.

Answer (score 0):

You might do an extension method to `IsNullOrEmpty()`:

```
public static bool IsNullOrEmpty(this string value) => string.IsNullOrEmpty(str);
```

And then you can use it this way:

```
set { this.reason = value.IsNullOrEmpty() ? "reason not explicited" : value; }
```